# Preventing overflow and maintaining aspect ratio with constrained height

Tags: html, css

I have a phone render that's sliced into 3x3 files with inequal proportions.

How can I place these images in a CSS grid so that the images don't cause blowout, don't overflow the grid container, but instead keep their aspect ratio, and are constrained by a defined height on the container (or any of it's parents, I guess)

```html
<!-- wip -->
<div class="h-[80vh]">
  <div class="h-full grid grid-cols-[max-content,max-content,max-content]">
    <img src="/images/top-left@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/top-center@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/top-right@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/left@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/center@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/right@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/bottom-left@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/bottom-center@3x.png" />
    <img src="/images/bottom-right@3x.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The sliced image:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uwYA.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzklc.png]

Perhaps asking this to be solved with `display: grid` is dangerously close to an XY Problem, but I think `grid` makes my next steps much easier

Comment: You are talking about an XY problem, but you are not explaining what you're trying to achieve. With that we could tell you if that is the case :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a grid, since all grid cells are the same size.

I do not really understand the need to have 9 parts like that... If I base myself on this sentence: "keep their aspect ratio, and are constrained by a defined height on the container", this is exactly the behaviour of a background image. You could have a simple div, with a simple background-image.

My guess is that you'd like to replace the middle content? You'd then add the correct paddings to have the content area be exactly your main part.

If, for some reason it absolutely needs to be 9 different images, I'd simply give them their sizes in percentage to the total, so they will keep correct sizes.

```
<div class="h-[80vh]">
    <img src="/images/top-left@3x.png" width=10% height=10%/>
    <img src="/images/top-center@3x.png" width=80% height=10%/>
    <img src="/images/top-right@3x.png" width=10% height=10%/>
    <img src="/images/left@3x.png" width=10% height=80%/>
    <img src="/images/center@3x.png" width=80% height=80%/>
    <img src="/images/right@3x.png" width=10% height=80%/>
    <img src="/images/bottom-left@3x.png" width=10% height=10%/>
    <img src="/images/bottom-center@3x.png" width=80% height=10%/>
    <img src="/images/bottom-right@3x.png" width=10% height=10%/>
</div>
```

Percentages are "almost" random just for the example.

You could also have only 3 or 5 images instead of the 9. By grouping the 3 header images together and the 3 footer images. You'd have only the middle with 3, if again that is to be able to change the Main part.